# How to successfully installing IDA patching plugin

Tags: windows, plugins, disassembly, ida

I'd like to use the plugin: `Tool Release: IDA Patcher` [text](https://iphelix.medium.com/tool-release-ida-patcher-71ba87eb64a9) but when i follow the instructions and just copy the `idapatcher.py` to `IDA/plugins` i get:

```
C:\Users\...\IDA PRO 7.5 SP3\plugins\idapatcher.py: invalid syntax (C:/Users/Darek/IDA PRO 7.5 SP3/plugins/idapatcher.py, line 367) 

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Darek\IDA PRO 7.5 SP3\python\3\ida_idaapi.py", line 615, in IDAPython_ExecScript code = compile(raw.decode(encoding), script, 'exec') 

File "C:/Users/Darek/IDA PRO 7.5 SP3/plugins/idapatcher.py", line 367 except Exception, e:^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here are my specs: IDA PRO v7.5 SP3, Win 10, Python v3.9.2.